# Can someone help me with executing these commands?

Tags: linux, command-line

I have been given some questions to start me off with displaying data using linux commands.

If someone could give me some pointers on how to execute these commands i would be very grateful.

Given the attached datasource.log, using only Linux commands:

1. Display the number of warnings in the log file
2. Display all the warning lines in the log file
3. Display all lines with status “UP” or “DOWN”
4. Display all the lines within the time frame 9:26:18 - 9:26:55

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Would this be right for the first one?

$ grep “Warning” datasource.log | wc -1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` command to display patterns in log file like:

a- Display "warning":

`grep warning file.log`

b- Display "UP" or "DOWN":

`grep -E 'UP|DOWN' file.log`

c- For counting you can use `wc -l`:

`grep warning file.log | wc -l`

c- For time frame:

`grep "9:26:[18-55]" file.log`

Comment: Hi ahmed, thanks for your reply, great that is pretty much what i got, can you explain why you need grep -E for the display up, down one?

Also, this is what i got for the time frame one: 
'sed -n '/9:26:18/ , /9:26:55/p'  datasource.log'. Do you think doing it using grep is better?

Comment: grep -E will display any line with "UP" or "DOWN". and sed command did the same grep command but I think grep is easier for your need.

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.